# TYPO3: exec_SELECTquery with where clause

Tags: database, select, typo3

The following `select` returns an empty result set, although it shoudn't:

`$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery('*', 'tx_xmluploader_xml_import_tree', 'xml_import_id='.$xml_import_id);`

`$xml_import_id` is set. And it works if I remove the `where` clause..

Thanks

---

I still don't understand why it doesn't work.. A simple workaround suggested by a coleague:

```
// select all from the db     
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery('*', 'tx_xmluploader_xml_import_tree');

while( $entry = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc() )
{  
   if( $entry['xml_import_id'] == $xml_import_id ) {
      ....
   }    
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "isn't working for me"? Empty result set? Error message?

Comment: It returns an empty result set.

Comment: Just to get updated: Are any of these answers working for you?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure the following is set in localconf.php:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['SYS']['sqlDebug'] = '1';   
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['debug'] = '1';
```

Then try

```
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->SELECTquery('*', 'tx_xmluploader_xml_import_tree', 'xml_import_id='.$xml_import_id);
t3lib_div::debug($res);
```

Result is the output of the query in the frontend. You can then execute it in MySQL for debugging.

Comment: I have seen `t3lib_div::debug();` used once in a backend module, but in the frontend all I get is this: `| debug |`.

Comment: Then the value you passed to debug is empty. Note that the function I suggested is `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->SELECTquery` (without the `exec_` prefix). Also try, for a test, `t3lib_div::debug('Testing debug function');`

Comment: The result of the debug was: SELECT * FROM tx_xmluploader_xml_import_tree WHERE xml_import_id=9. I executed the query in MySQL and it worked. What could be wrong then? :( Thanks..

Comment: That is strange behaviour. Maybe the regarding record (in tx_xmluploader_xml_import_tree) is set to deleted = 1? 
But then you should nevertheless see it in your output.
Which TYPO3 version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

a) make sure $xml_import_id actually has a value (one which is in the database as well)

b) Try this:

```
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTquery(
   '*',
   'tx_xmluploader_xml_import_tree',
   "xml_import_id='".$xml_import_id."'"
);
```

How do you process the result?
How does your expected $xml_import_id value look like?

cu
Roman

Comment: $xml_import_id is 9, as in my database. I tried `print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($res))` - it doesn't print anything.

Comment: I tried `"xml_import_id='".$xml_import_id."'"` as well, but $res is still empty.